# Syntax SQL error on IF EXISTS statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

in my java project I need to check if a row exists in a table.
In case of exist, I need to Update; if not, I need to create it. The Sql syntax to do this should be:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column4='"+int4+"' AND column5='"+int5+"') "
                +"BEGIN "
+ "UPDATE table1"
+ "SET column1='"+int1+"', column2='"+int2+"' "
+ "WHERE column4='"+int4+"' and column5='"+int5+"' "
+ "END "
+ "ELSE"
+ "INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column4, column5, column3) "
                + "VALUES ('" + int1 + "',"
                + "'" + int2 + "',"
                + "'" + int4 + "',"
                + "'" + int5 + "',"
                + "'" + int3 +"');
```

where `int1, int2, int3, int4, int5` are integer values.
Well, if I put this code I have an Sql syntax error on my java compiler :

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column4='1' AND column5='0') BEGIN UPDATE' at line 1
```

But I can'y see the error

Comment: print the above line in console,then check it in mysql.You will get to know whether there are any error or not

Comment: You can use control statements like `if` **only** in functions or procedures.

Comment: Thank you. in which way you would resolve this problem?

Comment: Use `case` and use the query as a temporary table for another select query.

Comment: you can check if the column exists if you query the `information_schema.columns` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an error because in MySQL you can't use conditional statement [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) other than in stored routines (stored procedure, stored function, trigger).

What you need is so called `UPSERT` which you can achieve in MySQL with [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). In order for it to work you have to have a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `column4` and `column5`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD UNIQUE (column4, column5);
```

Now your `INSERT` statement might look like

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column4, column5, column3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1=VALUES(column1), column2=VALUES(column2);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb1b95/1)** demo

***On a side note:** Use **parameterized queries** instead of interpolating query strings. I'm not an expert in Java but I'm sure it has a first class infrastructure for that. Otherwise you are wide open to SQL-injections.*

Comment: @Bernheart Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help. The compiler print an error highlighting `INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column4, column5, column3)`. Sorry for being late, I had a very busy day!